# Detect if key was pressed anytime

Tags: python, loops

I want to detect if the key `H` was pressed in anytime, and not just one time.

I am currently using the `keyboard` module like that:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('h'):
        print("H pressed")
        break
```

So, if I pressed `H` it will output `H pressed`, but if I pressed `H` again nothing will happen because I've breaked the while loop.

I want it to work again and not only one time key detection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you don't want to break out of the loop -- why have `break`?

Comment: Why are you breaking the loop.? Simply put rest of the conditions in `elif` block.

Comment: remove 'break' and see

Comment: If I removed break it will loop `H pressed` forever - @JohnColeman @pyd

Comment: @MatrixCow08 How about checking for a special key like Escape key to break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import keyboard as kd
kd.on_press_key("H",lambda _:print("You pressed Key H"))
```

It will run the command and continue but if you press the key `H` anytime , it will print.

Or There is a simpler way to do this:

```
import keyboard as kd
while True:
    if "H" in kd.read_key():print("You pressed Key H")
```

According to your code, remove `break`:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('h'):
        print("H pressed")
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using the `keyboard` module and quite close to your code:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    keyboard.wait("h")
    print("H pressed")
```